# Dictionary that has the most examples?

Tags: example

recently I thought of getting a new dictionary. What is the dictionary that has the most examples (especially sentences examples)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for resources, and not about the English language.

Comment: It's pretty much a function of the size, which is pretty much a function of the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED2.

Number of quotations: 2,436,600

http://public.oed.com/history-of-the-oed/dictionary-facts/

As per Mary Lou, the OED2 comes in two versions: the first is the 20 volume dictionary, the price of which costs 995 new on Amazon [1]; the second is a compact, micrographic version, which costs 1/3 of the price of the 20 volume set at $377 on Amazon [2] and isn't portable either as it is gigantic.

As for portable dictionaries, I would say that it depends on which side of the pond you're on; if you're English, you could probably go for a pocket OED (price on Amazon: $13.26 [3]) or pocket Collins English Dictionary (price on Amazon: $9.38 [4]).

If you're American, then pocket Websters (price on Amazon: $5.95 [5]) is about the only one I know of that has a pocket dictionary in America; I would've recommended American Heritage as well, but it seems it doesn't have a pocket dictionary from my search.

On all of these dictionaries, I can't say which has the most example sentences as I've never owned any pocket other than Websters, which didn't have any but as its copyright is 2003, its newer *may* have them.

I suggest pocket dictionaries as you said you were looking for portable ones and thus chose to omit desk dictionaries, with the exception of my original answer.

[1] [http://www.amazon.com/Oxford-English-Dictionary-Vols-1-20/dp/0198611862/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446031161&sr=1-1&keywords=Oxford+20+vol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198611862).

[2] [http://www.amazon.com/Dictionary-Complete-Reproduced-Micrographically-slipcase/dp/0198612583/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446031941&sr=1-1&keywords=oxford+english+dictionary+compact](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198612583)

[3] [http://www.amazon.com/Pocket-Oxford-English-Dictionary-Dictionaries/dp/0199666156/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446031113&sr=1-1&keywords=pocket+oxford+english+dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199666156)

[4] [http://www.amazon.com/Collins-English-Dictionary-Pocket/dp/0007450559/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446030297&sr=1-4&keywords=Pocket+Collins+English+dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0007450559)

[5] [http://www.amazon.com/Merriam-Websters-Pocket-Dictionary-Merriam-Webster/dp/0877795304/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1446031067&sr=1-1&keywords=Pocket+Websters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877795304)

Comment: Best mention how much it costs too. It's quite steep, but if you are lucky enough to be a member of an English library you can enjoy free online access—at least I think it works that way.

Comment: I have checked OED before, but it has 20 volumes. 20 volumes aren't portable for me. Any other choices?

Comment: @EnglishGuy-David please do not ask new questions in comments. Jasper answered your original question correctly, you should have stated that you had discarded OED in your original (off-topic) question.

Comment: If price is not an issue but portability is, you could try the online subscription.

Comment: Webster's indeed is the dictionary of choice in America. Their college dictionary is about 4 pounds in weight and costs 9 USD or so gently used on Amazon. It gives access to their unabridged online. The college has not as many examples as I would like. The unabridged is about 10 pounds and 50 USD on sale

Comment: @EnglishGuy-David Get the OED on CD — weighs nothing.